# How do polymorphic inline caches work with mutable types?

Tags: javascript, vm-implementation, dynamic-typing, cache-invalidation, polymorphic-functions

A polymorphic inline cache(PIC) works by caching the actual method by the type of the object, in order to avoid the expensive lookup procedures (usually a hashtable lookup).

How does one handle the type comparison if the type objects are mutable (i.e. the method might be monkey patched into something different at run time)?

The one idea I've come up with would be a "class counter" that gets incremented each time a method is adjusted, however this seems like it would be exceptionally expensive in a heavily monkey patched environment, since it would kill all the PICs for that class, even if the methods for them weren't altered.

I'm sure there must be a good solution to this, as this issue is directly applicable to JavaScript, and AFAIK all three of the big JavaScript virtual machines have PICs.

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

In V8, I would assume that monkeypatching would change the "hidden class" ("map" is SELF terminology) of the object. That would work in you monkey patched the object itself.

If you monkey patched the class (can you do that is JS?), I would guess it invalidates all PICs, since this is probably rare. Alternatively, it might recompile the old method to dispatch straight to the new method (after a type check I guess)

As an aside, I don't think the other "big 3" use PICs, actually. I presume you mean squirrelfish and tracemonkey. The former is an interpreter, and the latter focusses on the tracing approach, and I don't recall hearing anything about PICs. In fact, I don't think tracemonkey does anything cool at all for objects, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Type inference is used:

> SpiderMonkey mainly uses type inference to determine which properties are being accessed; in cases where type inference does not find the exact shape of the object being accessed, SpiderMonkey uses a PIC (polymorphic inline caches) to store the result of the lookup.
>
> An additional form of profiling feedback are the Baseline JIT's polymorphic inline caches. Polymorphic inline caches are a classic technique for optimizing dynamic dispatch that originated in the Smalltalk community.

De-optimization is the name of the process that happens when type inference fails:

> Of course, JavaScript being a dynamically typed language, ocassionally the assumption about the hidden class of the object will be incorrect, and in that case V8 will "de-optimize" and revert back to the original version of the method call in which the objects hidden class is checked.

Multiple compilers are necessary for this to work:

> Technically it means that the compiler is in fact two compilers: a base compiler and an "optimizer". (Or even more, if we are talking about JSC and SpiderMonkey). The concept is quite sound and can yield incredible performance, but there is a nuance: the optimized code may be "deoptimized" in various places, not just at the entry point, meaning that the environment (local variables, arguments, context) should be mapped and moved around.
>
> Ion, being the optimizing compiler, does not support compiling in debug mode checks. Indeed, implementing such support is of dubious utility, as its optimizations would make onStep invocations at best infelicitous. To support debug mode, optimized code on the stack are deoptimized and bailed out to Baseline. That is, the Ion frame on the stack is overwritten with a reconstructed Baseline frame corresponding to the same location in which Ion code is currently executing.

Debugging is done via dynamic deoptimization:

> We can do better. The dream of the 90s, embodied in the Self language, is alive in JavaScript. We can adapt Self’s dynamic deoptimization via on-stack replacement technique to debug even optimized code. The core idea of a `debug mode OSR` is simple: when debugging is required, we deoptimize and recompile JITed code on the stack, patching return addresses as we go. One might say it is almost elegant, if not for the exacting violence it inflicts on stack frames.
>
> Consider the following JavaScript function:

```
function foo(o) { return o.f + o.g; }
```

> In this example, the property accesses may lead to anything from a simple load from well-known locations in the heap to invocations of getters or even complicated DOM traps, like if `o` were a document object and `f` were the name of an element in the page. The Baseline JIT will initially execute these property accesses as fully polymorphic dispatch. But as it does so it will record the steps it takes, and will then modify the heap accesses in-place to be caches of the necessary steps to repeat a similar access in the future. For example, if the object has a property `f` at offset 16 from the base of the object, then the code will be modified to first quickly check if the incoming object consists of a property `f` at offset 16 and then perform the load. These caches are said to be inline because they are represented entirely as generated machine code. They are said to be polymorphic because if different object structures are encountered, the machine code is modified to switch on the previously encountered object types before doing a fully dynamic property lookup. When the DFG compiles this code, it will check if the inline cache is monomorphic – optimized for just one object structure – and if so, it will emit just a check for that object structure followed by the direct load. In this example, if o was always an object with properties `f` and `g` at invariant offsets, then the DFG would only need to emit one type check for `o` followed by two direct loads.

[image: Data Flow Just-in-Time Compiler (DFG JIT) Optimization Pipeline]

[image: Faster-Than-Light Just-in-Time Compiler (FTL JIT) Optimization Pipeline]

**References**

- [Deoptimize me not, v8](http://darksi.de/a.deoptimize-me-not/)
- [Javascript Hidden Classes and Inline Caching in V8](http://richardartoul.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/04/26/hidden-classes.html)
- [Debugging in the Time of JITs](http://rfrn.org/%7Eshu/2014/05/14/debugging-in-the-time-of-jits.html)
- [IonMonkey: Evil on your behalf | JavaScript](https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2016/07/05/ionmonkey-evil-on-your-behalf/)
- [Optimization killers · petkaantonov/bluebird Wiki](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers)
- [Optimizing Dynamically-Typed Object-Oriented Languages with Polymorphic Inline Caches (pdf)](http://hoelzle.org/publications/ecoop91.pdf)
- [Deoptimization for Dynamic Language JITs on Typed, Stack-based Virtual Machines (pdf)](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/%7Emkedlaya/VEE14-final44.pdf)
- [Javascript var vs let (de)optimization/slowdown issue in v8 and SpiderMonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153889/javascript-var-vs-let-deoptimization-slowdown-issue-in-v8-and-spidermonkey)
- [chakracore msjunit: Test deoptimization after inlined call.](https://github.com/nodejs/node-chakracore/blob/master/deps/v8/test/mjsunit/compiler/regress-deopt-call-as-function.js#L28)
- [chakracore msjunit: Test inlining and deoptimization of functions accessing and modifying the arguments object in strict mode with mismatched arguments count](https://github.com/nodejs/node-chakracore/blob/master/deps/v8/test/mjsunit/compiler/inline-arguments.js#L208)
- [Nested Refinement Types for JavaScript (pdf)](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Erchugh/static/papers/chugh-dissertation.pdf)
- [Introducing the WebKit FTL JIT | WebKit](https://webkit.org/blog/3362/introducing-the-webkit-ftl-jit/)