# Javascript temporal dead zone NodeJS 7.9.0 performance decrease?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, variable-declaration

I have noticed in an other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37792934/why-is-let-slower-than-var-in-a-for-loop-in-nodejs) the performance difference in loops while using `let` and `var` variables declaration.

The initial  question is correctly answered that using `let` in the **for loop** is slower since `let` creates a new scope for each iteration to hold the value of `let` declared variable. More work to be done, so it is normal to be slower. Just as reference, I give the code and the results in NodeJS (7.9.0) execution time:

*Please note that all javascript code below regards NodeJS version 7.9.0*

**Regular Code:**

```
'use strict';
console.time('var');
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
console.timeEnd('var');


console.time('let');
for (let j = 0; j < 100000000; j++) {}
console.timeEnd('let');
```

**Output:**

```
var: 55.792ms
let: 247.123ms
```

In order to avoid the extra scope declaration for `j` in every iteration of the loop, we declare the `j` variable just before the loop. One would expect that this should now make the `let` loop performance match the one of `var`. **BUT NO!!!** This is the code and the result for reference:

**Code with `let` defined before loop:**

```
'use strict';
console.time('var');
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
console.timeEnd('var');


console.time('let');
let j;
for (j = 0; j < 100000000; j++) {}
console.timeEnd('let');
```

**Output:**

```
var: 231.249ms
let: 233.485ms
```

We can see that, not only the `let` loop did not get any faster but also the `var` loop became as slow as the `let` one!!! The only explanation for this is that since we are not in any block or function, both variables are declared in the **global** module scope. However as referenced [here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_variables.html#sec_temporal-dead-zone), the `let` declaration of the variable in the middle of the scope, creates a **temporal dead zone**, which leaves the variable `j` uninitialized, while the `var` initializes the variable as defined.

So running code in a temporal dead zone although the uninitialized variable is not referenced, must be quite slower....

Finally to show the deference, we declare the `j` variable on top of the program to show the results of running it without the **temporal dead zone**.

**Code without temporal dead zone:**

```
'use strict';
let j;
console.time('var');
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
console.timeEnd('var');


console.time('let');
for (j = 0; j < 100000000; j++) {}
console.timeEnd('let');
```

**Output:**

```
var: 55.586ms
let: 55.009ms
```

**Now both `let` and `var` loops have similar optimized performance!**

Does anyone know whether my assumption about temporal dead zone performance is correct, or provide a different explanation???

Comment: interesting question - upvoted, you should try that in other environments too.

Comment: i am also very curious about that one, could be something about memory allocation

Comment: This is absolutely related to the TDZ.  See the ["Performance" bullet point here](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified#tdz-is-everywhere-except-in-transpilers-and-engines).  It sort of makes sense in my head, but not well enough for me to write up an answer.

Comment: Isn't the performance bullet only referencing to transpilers?

Comment: Further discussion [on esdiscuss](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/performance-concern-with-let-const)

Comment: @mitsos1os No - it's using the performance impact and complexity of having to do those checks as a reason that transpilers might not be properly enforcing the TDZ.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes you are right, I read it fast...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript var vs let (de)optimization/slowdown issue in v8 and SpiderMonkey](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43153889/1048572)?

Answer (score 2):

This is the output of your tests on several versions of Node:

```
node-v4.0.0
var: 92ms
let: 336ms
var: 220ms
let: 230ms
=====
node-v4.2.2
var: 95ms
let: 342ms
var: 228ms
let: 233ms
=====
node-v5.1.0
var: 93.418ms
let: 342.050ms
var: 264.895ms
let: 228.310ms
=====
node-v5.12.0
var: 103.254ms
let: 340.990ms
var: 228.698ms
let: 228.213ms
=====
node-v6.3.1
var: 109.476ms
let: 338.127ms
var: 232.381ms
let: 241.795ms
=====
node-v6.5.0
var: 96.630ms
let: 339.570ms
var: 686.631ms
let: 612.820ms
=====
node-v6.7.0
var: 106.760ms
let: 349.677ms
var: 690.753ms
let: 587.444ms
=====
node-v7.0.0
var: 95.366ms
let: 333.880ms
var: 222.668ms
let: 234.101ms
=====
node-v7.4.0
var: 101.074ms
let: 330.778ms
var: 221.869ms
let: 238.053ms
=====
node-v7.8.0
var: 93.604ms
let: 338.447ms
var: 224.263ms
let: 233.313ms
=====
node-v7.9.0
var: 92.622ms
let: 333.552ms
var: 275.980ms
let: 230.990ms
```

Those are not all Node versions, just the ones that I have installed locally so it's easy to test.

Apparently the behavior is consistent in most of the versions: putting `let` outside of the loop makes it slightly faster, but it makes the `var` somewhere else much slower.

It seems that something bad happened in 6.5.0 but it was fixed 7.x.

It can leave some place for optimization but I wouldn't worry too much about `var` getting slower. I would be more interested of making `let` faster.

Making those examples into functions and letting them run several times can make the JIT kick in and optimize the functions so the results may differ from what you see when everything is run for the first time.